# Stack Overflow homepage not loading new questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, homepage, web-sockets

The Stack Overflow homepage used to load more questions without reloading the page. Now, I have to reload the page to see new questions. This happened after the change they made to the design of the site. Is this a bug in the site or something wrong with my browser? I am using the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: actually i don't think it's been doing that for a long time, like more than a year. i figured it was turned off because of how many new questions get added. i think you need to to be sitting on a tag's "Newest" tab or any "Active" tab to get the live updates

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This has [never worked on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox):

> Stack Overflow has a massive amount of activity so we have decided to limit this feature to tags only. Both the "newest" and "active" tab will have updates after first selecting a tag or tag combination.

That's from the announcement of the feature back in 2012, and has remained the case ever since.

Comment: I wish this would work for the “tag combination” `intags:mine`.

Comment: @Xufox - You can use a combination of many tags though, just separate them with or in the search box. For example: `[javascript] or [html] or [css] or [jquery] or [regex]`. Using that as your search will cause the posts to be displayed as they come in.

Comment: @TravisJ I know, but this requires updating the search when my favorite tags change. Ideally, the “my tags” tab should be sortable by newest. I could write a userscript to automatically search with my favorite tags…